# problemas con resulset y matriz

Tags: array, eclipse, matrices

Hola tengo el siguiente código, y el problema es que no puedo pasarle el resultado del resulset a la matriz para usarla luego en otra clase para llenar una tabla y generar un archivo pdf,
Siempre me dice en los out print que el valor es NULL aunque el resulset muestra los datos que necesito. Lo que quiero es que la matriz datos tabla tome los datos del resulset.

```
////boton Propietarios  
JButton btnPropietarios = new JButton("Propietarios");
btnPropietarios.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    while (modelo.getRowCount() > 0) modelo.removeRow(0);
    a=0;
    try {
        result = null;
        Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(Menuppal1.ruta);
        PreparedStatement st = conexion.prepareStatement("select * from PROPI");
        result = st.executeQuery();
        //dese aqui
        int h=0;
        int g =0;
        Object Datosfila[] = new Object[4];
        String datostabla[][] = new String[4] [10000];
        while (result.next()){// Se rellena cada posición del array con una de las columnas de la tabla en base de datos.
            for (i=0; i<Datosfila.length; i++){
                Datosfila[i] = result.getObject(i+1);
                modelo.addRow(Datosfila);
                a++;
                txtsolventes.setText(Integer.toString(a));
                ///////
                datostabla[g][h] = (String) result.getObject(i+1);
                h++;
                g++;
                System.out.println(datostabla[g][h]);
                System.out.println("valor de g y h :" +g+ "====" + h);
                System.out.println("valor del result :" +result.getString(i+1));
                System.out.println("matriz["+g+"] ["+h+"]=" + datostabla[g] [h]);
                if (g==3){
                    g=0;
                }
            }
            ///////////////
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sería mejor que acotaras el código a donde tengas el problema. Pegar la clase entera hace que sea difícil y costoso verlo.

Comment: Ok dani gracias por la sugerencia. a eso voy

Comment: lo he solucionado, el problema ahora es que no se como convertirla en static para verla desde la otra clase, alguna idea? Por Favor.

Comment: static no te da la visibilidad desde otra clase. Para poder verla tiene que ser public (dependiendo de donde esten ambas clases podrian valer otros valores)